# Making node array accessible in view

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am trying to create a basic messaging system using express/nodejs. While I am able to emit messages to all users successfully. I need for users to be able to message each other in a 1-to-1 private manner.

What I am trying to do below is simple. When a user logs in, once the session has been validated, store the user object in the `clients` array and make this array accessible in the view -- that's it!

The intention is that this array will to grow on the server as users log in and I'll need to make it accessibly in the view, so I can generate a list of online users that are available for chat.

I have tried several different approaches, the approach below results in an empty array in the view.

My goal is to simply store online users in an array on the server as they log in and have that array accessible in the view.

I appreciate any suggestions.

index.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql       = require('mysql');
var session     = require('client-sessions');
var server      = require('http').createServer( app );
var io          = require('socket.io').listen( server );
var clients = [];

app.locals.delimiters = '<% %>';


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.session && req.session.user.username){
        mysql.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND pass = ? LIMIT 1", [req.session.user.username, req.session.user.pass], function(error, results, fields){
            if(results.length === 0){
                req.session.reset();
                res.redirect('/login');
            }else{
                res.locals.user = results[0];

                io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
                    clients.push({user : res.locals.user, socket : socket});
                });

                res.render('index');
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});

server.listen( 3331 ); //chat port

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){  

    //load all users
    socket.on('load users', function(){
       io.emit('load users', {clients : clients});      
    });

    socket.on('error', function(err){
        console.error(err.stack);
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.hjs

```
<div class="messenger-user" ng-repeat="n in clients">
    <div class="avatar-icon glyphicon glyphicon-user">
    </div>
    <div class="user-meta">
        {{n.user.firstname}} {{n.user.lastname}}
    </div>
</div>
```

index.hjs JavaScript

```
socket.emit('load users', function(clients){
    $scope.clients = clients;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Makes perfect sense. It sends an empty array because you send it before populating it.

Currently :
1) A MySQL query is launched to retrieve and populate the users array.

2) Meanwhile, a socket `on 'connection'` event is triggered (line 24), that emits the users array, which is currently empty.

3) Your MySQL query ends (line 3) and gets back with the data you want.

4) Inside the callback function, you set *another* listener for `io.sockets.on('connection')`. It's too late, because you already set one, and the connection event already happened. So you have two listeners for the same event, and the second one never triggers.

What you should do is wait for the SQL query to end, *then* populate your array and emit it to the client.

**Edit 2 :** Don't use both HTTP connection and socket for authentication. You're trying to store a user object from a HTTP request, together with a socket that is unrelated to the HTTP request. Do everything with the sockets :

```
var clients = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('credentials', function(data){ // data == { "username":"John" , "password":"123456" }
        login(data, socket); // sending credentials and socket to the login function, so both are defined there.
    })
    socket.on('error', function(err){
        console.error(err.stack);
    });
});

function login(data, socket){
    mysql.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+data.username+"' AND pass='"+data.password+"' LIMIT 1", [req.session.user.username, req.session.user.pass], function(error, results, fields){
        if(!results.length){
            req.session.reset();
            res.redirect('/login');
        }else{
            clients.push({user : results[0], socket : socket}); // Both defined!
            io.emit('load users', {clients : clients});
            res.render('index');
        }
    });
}

server.listen( 3331 ); //chat port
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am currently populating my array when once the SQL query executed successfully. Is there a way to accomplish this with one `connection` event?

Comment: You have to have only one 'connection' listener anyway. Once the array is populated, send it through the socket. Sending it 'on connection' is useless if it's empty. Why do you absolutely want to send it on connection? Let the client connect and wait, and emit the array when it's ready to be sent.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been trying to accomplish, with no success. How can we know when 'its ready to be sent'. I feel like this is more complicated than it needs to be:( I am just trying to populate an array for every user that logs in and send it over to the view ...

Comment: It's ready to be sent when it's populated :) Which means in your callback function that fills it. I have updated my andswer and added some code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I tried something similar, the problem is, `res.locals.user` is undefined in your example. This is why I put the connection event inside the `get()` function initially, so `socket` and `res` are both defined.

Comment: `res` is the HTTP's response object. It's used to answer the client who made the HTTP request. It's not even related to your logic or socket.io. I didn't even consider this line, but now that you mention it, why do you do `res.locals.user`? What is that for?

Comment: That is the user object. I need it to create a list of online users  available to chat on the client side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79547/discussion-between-anchovylegend-and-jeremy-thille).

Comment: I think I start to understand what you want to do. You want to store both the socket from socketIO AND the user from the database. That's difficult, because the socket comes from one connection (socketIO), and the user from another one (HTTP), so they're basically unrelated. You should do everything using socketIO, with `socket.on('credentials',...`, then launch your mysql query from these credentials. Then everything will be defined : user and socket. That's quite a tough one. I'll try and update my answer again.